# Metaclasses and __slots__?

Tags: python

So, I am reading a bit about metaclasses in Python, and how `type()`'s three-argument alter-ego is used to dynamically create classes.  However, the third argument is usually a `dict` that initializes the to-be created class' `__dict__` variable.

If I want to dynamically create classes based on a metaclass that uses `__slots__` instead of `__dict__`, how might I do this?  Is `type()` still used in some fashion along with overriding `__new__()`?

As an FYI, I am aware of the proper uses for `__slots__`, to save memory when creating large numbers of a class versus abusing it to enforce a form of type-safety.

Example of a normal (new-style) class that sets `__metaclass__` and uses a `__dict__`:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dctn):
        # Do something unique ...
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dctn)

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

In the above, `type.__new__()` is called and the fourth argument (which becomes the third when actually used) creates a `__dict__` in `Foo`.  But if I wanted to modify `Meta` to include `__slots__`, then I have no dictionary to pass on to `type()`'s `__new__()` function (as far as I know -- I haven't tested any of this yet, just pondering and trying to find some kind of a use-case scenario).

**Edit:** A quick, but untested guess, is to take a dict of the values to be put into the `__slots__` variables and pass it to `type.__new__()`.  Then add an `__init__()` to `Meta` that populates the `__slots__` variables from the dict.  Although, I am not certain how that dict would reach `__init__()`, because the declaration of `__slots__` prevents `__dict__` from being created unless `__dict__` is defined in `__slots__`...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't create a type with a non-empty __slots__ attribute.  What you can do is insert a __slots__ attribute into the new class's dict, like this:

```
class Meta(type): 
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dctn):
         dctn['__slots__'] = ( 'x', )
         return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dctn)

 class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Now Foo has slotted attributes:

```
foo = Foo() 
foo.y = 1
```

throws

```
 AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'y'
```

Comment: This looks interesting.  I'll try it in a few minutes.

Comment: Never got around to testing this, but I think this technically answers the question.  I'll figure it out one day.

Comment: Just now logging back into SO in ages; this answer is ultimately what worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`dctn` in your example of a metaclass is the *class* dictionary, not the *instance* dictionary. `__slots__` replaces the *instance* dictionary. If you create two examples:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dctn):
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dctn)

class Foo1(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

class Foo2(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta
    __slots__ = ['a', 'b']
```

Then:

```
>>> f1 = Foo1()
>>> f2 = Foo2()
>>> f1.__dict__ is Foo1.__dict__
False
>>> f2.__dict__
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
AttributeError: 'Foo2' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

Comment: Okay, I am still learning the ropes on Python here and am starting to wrap my head around Python's mantra of "everything is an object" (similar to UNIX's "everything is a file").  Is it not possible to define `__slots__` in the Metaclass and have it propagated to classes created from the metaclass?  Or is this where a base class becomes more useful?  Or, would I want to combine both concepts?

Comment: Good question.  You certainly could define `__slots__` in the metaclass simply by adding to `dctn`.  However, subclassing from a base class would usually be a better approach.  Generally, if you're not sure if you need a metaclass, then you don't.

Comment: That's why I am trying to learn about metaclasses a bit more, so I can determine if I really do need them or not.  Note, I am coming off of a background in .NET where I had to contend with generics, interfaces, and single-inheritance, and never had formal training in OOP (just a few classes on good old C).  Trying to understand Python's rather....unique differences is proving to be quite interesting at times.  Much like one finds a way to convert a spork into a trebuchet that launches brussel sprouts across the table while at dinner.

Answer (score 2):

## More about **slots** defined in metaclasses.

if `type`'s subclass defines non-empty `__slots__`, Python throws a `TypeError` because of some [complicated implementation-related stuff](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/python/HowSlotsWorkI).

```
In [1]:

class Meta(type):
    __slots__ = ('x')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-1b16edef8eca> in <module>()
----> 1 class Meta(type):
      2     __slots__ = ('x')

TypeError: nonempty __slots__ not supported for subtype of 'type'
```

Empty `__slots__` on the other hand don't produce any errors, but seam to have no effect.

```
In [2]:

class Meta(type):
    __slots__ = ()

class Foo(metaclass=Meta):
    pass

type(Foo)

Out [2]:

__main__.Meta

In [3]:

Foo.y = 42
Foo.y

Out [3]:

42

In [4]:

Foo.__dict__

Out [4]:

mappingproxy({'y': 42, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Foo' objects>, '__doc__': None, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Foo' objects>, '__module__': '__main__'})

In [5]:

foo = Meta('foo', (), {})
type(foo).__slots__

Out [5]:

()

In [6]:

foo.x = 42
foo.x

Out [6]:

42

In [7]:

foo.__dict__

Out [7]:

mappingproxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'foo' objects>, 'x': 42, '__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'foo' objects>})

In [8]:

# Testing on non-metaclasses. Just in case.
class Bar:
    __slots__ = ()

b = Bar()
b.__dict__

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-843730c66f3f> in <module>()
      3 
      4 b = Bar()
----> 5 b.__dict__

AttributeError: 'Bar' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```