# Can the name and the reference of a named tuple be different?

Tags: python, tuples, namedtuple

While reading `fmark`'s answer to the question [What are "named tuples" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python) I saw that the example given there had the same name and reference, i.e. the word `Point` appears twice in the following statement:

`Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')`

So I went to the original reference:
 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

 And here too I found two more examples:

```
EmployeeRecord = namedtuple('EmployeeRecord', 'name, age, title, department, paygrade')
Color = namedtuple('Color', 'red green blue')
```

Ideally words are not repeated in Python. For instance the whole line (for the the `Point` example) could be replaced by the following:

```
namedtuple('Point', 'x y')
```

**OR**

```
Point = namedtuple('x y')
```

Of course, that's assuming that the named tuple has to have the same name and reference. So my question is: when is it advisable (if at all it is permitted) that a named tuple should have a different name and reference? I am yet to come across an example.

Comment: `namedtuple('Point'...)` creates a class called 'Point', however without assigning it to some identifier you can only use it once, e.g. `point1 = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')(1, 0)`, and `type(point1) is <class '__main__.Point'>`. It is convenient to use an identifier that matches the class name, but it is not required, e.g. `Vertex = namedtuple('Point'...)`. A class is just another object in python and you would use a different name any time you would assign a different identifier to a class name, e.g. `class Point: ...    Vertex = Point`

Comment: In my opinion, the `namedtuple` module is a horrible mess and should have been written using metaclasses in the first place. It is still not at all clear to me [why it wasn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28184531), but if it had been, you would have the option of using class definitions for you named tuples, designating a metaclass, not needing to repeat the class name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it, it will just annoy you.

```
In [1]: import collections

In [2]: Point = collections.namedtuple('Rectangle', 'x y')

In [3]: Point(1, 2)
Out[3]: Rectangle(x=1, y=2)
```

This is confusing, don't do it unless you have a very good reason.

The reason why this happens is because `namedtuple()` is just a function, it has no special knowledge about how it is being used as a declaration.  In languages with macros, `namedtuple()` would be a macro which expands to a declaration instead.  So, rather than tack on a macro system or walk the call stack for the name, you have to specify name twice.

So it is one of Python's "warts", or a design compromise, depending on how you feel about it.

Comment: More particularly: the reason it happens is `namedtuple` was written using `exec` and string formatting instead of using metaclasses (which have the first `name` argument bound to the supplied metaclass instance name). Why is this? [Who knows.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28184531/why-doesnt-the-namedtuple-module-use-a-metaclass-to-create-nt-class-objects)

Comment: Though to be fair, you do still have to repeat the classname when using a metaclass as a class factory (e.g. `type('name', (object,),{})`).